# Execute function on childprocess.exec error

Tags: node.js, angular

I use electron and angular in my application.

I want to execute a function when I get an error by using childprocess.exec

Here is the code :

```
this.electronService.childProcess.exec(this.currentTerminal.cmd, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        this.toastr.success('Hello world!', 'Toastr fun!');
      }
});
```

The problem is that the toaster (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr) isn't shown directly, but after an other action (clicking a button for instance).

If I try my `this.toastr.success('Hello world!', 'Toastr fun!');` line without using the childProcess.exec callback, it works fine.

So I think that the problem come from the callback, and how I use it. But I don't really know how to do so...

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: It isn't an error, just my toastr that appears only after I do an other action.
https://gyazo.com/ba17124eacc5287617419b9588ca952b
In this gif, i click once on the button, and the toaster appears only after re-clicking the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using :

```
try {
      this.electronService.childProcess.execSync(this.currentTerminal.cmd);
} catch(ex) {
      this.toastr.error(this.translate.instant('UNKNOWN_TERMINAL') + this.currentTerminal.name);
}
```